# client side caching library/framework for thick clients

Tags: c#, .net, caching, memcached

I wrote a generic class that encapsulates a static hashtable with some put,get methods.
But I thought would be better if it has features where I can define some expiry time and some sync in place. All I need to do is cache some objects on the client. My application is a winform client and just need to cache some frequently used data items in memory.

I searched and found NCache, memcache and other server cache products and frameworks. But is there anything simple for client side caching in thick clients ?

Many Thanks,
Mani

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In .Net 4, Microsoft introduced the `System.Runtime.Caching` namespace. The most obvious choice in your scenario would likely be the `MemoryCache`:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache.aspx

Comment: yeah, going with it. [link](http://deanhume.com/Home/BlogPost/object-caching----net-4/37) has a wrapper as well if someone needs the same.